# Неправильная работа .net framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Хотел установить Visual Studio с помощью Visual Studio Installer`а. Но при попытке запустить Installer возникает ошибка (скриншот). 
[image]

Но у меня Windows 10, version: 1903. И вроде бы в неё должен быть встроен .net framework 4.8!!
Далее я пытался скачать .net framework с интернета, но при попытке установки, возникает такая ошибка:
[image]

Получется замкнутый круг!! Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо удалить все установленные версии .net framework.
Перезагрузить. 
А уже после установить нужную. 
Перезагрузить.